# Questions regarding the Newman-Kwart rearrangement

Tags: organosulfur-compounds

The [Newman-Kwart rearrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newman%E2%80%93Kwart_rearrangement) is a reaction that converts a phenol to a thiophenol by forming a phenolic thiocarbamate with two alkyl groups (methyl) on the nitrogen. This is acheived by reacting dimethylthiocarbomyl chloride with sodium phenoxide and then heating it:

[image]

([picture credit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newman%E2%80%93Kwart_rearrangement).  For their seminal publication, see Newman *et al.* mentioned below.)

In extension to this, Majetich *et al.* report alkyl isothiocyanates are able to react with saturated alkoxides to form sodium carbonimidothioate salts. The transition state depicted in the Newman rearrangement is strikingly similar to the salt produced from nucleophilic attack of the alkoxide on isothiocyanate where the sulfur atom bears the negative charge in both cases with the exception that in the rearrangement the nitrogen has a positive charge, but the sodium has the positive in the salt in the latter reaction.  The authors illustrate this with the following scheme:

[image]

(Majetich *et al.*, *loc. cit.*)

My questions are:

- Can a sodium carbonimidothioate salt undergo a similar rearrangement?
- What if we just add crown ethers to the reaction mixture.  Will that remove the sodium and trigger the reaction? I am interested in the 2-mercaptopyridine which is cited as occurring readily at room temperature.

**references**

Newman, M. S. and Karnes, H. A. *J. Org. Chem.* **1966**, *31*, 3980-3984, [doi 10.1021/jo01350a023](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01350a023).

Majetich, G.; Irvin, T. C.; Thompson, S. B. *Tet. Lett.* **2015**, *56*, 3326-3329, [doi 10.1016/j.tetlet.2015.01.086](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tetlet.2015.01.086).

Comment: Your links don't work

Comment: For future reference: 1) If you reference work, cite the original source at the publishers.  (There are nationwide federations which might offer you access to scientific publications [especially more elder ones/keyword rolling paywall] regardless of affiliation to a scientific institute, e.g. at public research/state libraries, too.) 2) Keep in mind a substantial portion of chemistry.se's readers uses the page to improve their understanding of chemistry. The addition of illustrations/reaction schemes may ease to grasp *the context* of your question.

Comment: If you are interested in the 2-mercatopyridine the direct displacement of the halogen from 2-halopridines is straightforward.